# C# OpenGL OpenTK - Camera moves away from drawings as I adjust eye.X value

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, camera-matrix

I've been trying to set up a camera in OpenGL for a few days now, but I just can't get it working properly. 
As the eye.X or eye.Y value increases/decreases, instead of "looking arround", the camera(I know there is no such thing as a camera...) moves away/gets closer to the drawings!

I hope following information can help you.(I also uploaded a Video, which is showing the error):
*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlD5X0EzkUw*

These are my ModelView calculations on **OnUpdateFrame**.

```
_worldPosition = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(_worldX, _worldY, _worldZ);
_cameraMatrix = Matrix4.LookAt(eye.X, eye.Y, eye.Z, center.X, center.Y, center.Z, up.X, up.Y, up.Z);

_modelViewMatrix = _worldPosition * _cameraMatrix;
```

Here, I adjust the values with **OnMouseMove** function:

```
if (_mouseDown)
{
     _mousePos.X = 2.0f * Mouse.X / Width - 1;
     _mousePos.Y = 2.0f * Mouse.Y / Width - 1;

     _mouseDeltaY = (_mousePosOld.Y - _mousePos.Y) / 10;
     _mouseDeltaX = (_mousePosOld.X - _mousePos.X) / 10;

     eye.X -= _mouseDeltaX;
     eye.Y -= _mouseDeltaY;
}
```

And finally my **Vertex shader**:

```
#version 440 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;

layout(location = 2) uniform  mat4 projectionMatrix;
layout (location = 3) uniform  mat4 modelViewMatrix;

out vec4 vs_color;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * position;
    vs_color = color;
}
```

Comment: Your matrix multiplication order is inconsistent. I don't know which conventions you are supposed to use, but your vertex transformation seems to end up as `proj * model * view * vertex` which does not make sense in any convention.

Comment: @derhass No, it's OpenTK. `_modelViewMatrix = _worldPosition * _cameraMatrix;` is fine. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976750/opengl-4-2-lookat-matrix-only-works-with-z-value-for-eye-position/57978635#57978635)

Comment: @noob. If you want to look around, then you have to modify `center` rather than `eye`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Well I did not know that, thx :). But is it normal, that I can't do a full rotation? I mean it starts slowing down, as I further turn right/left or up/down. `Center` still increases.

Comment: @noob. For a rotation `center` has to rotate around `eye`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I am not sure if we are on the same level. Sorry for bad english. 

With rotation I do not mean to rotate arround a object. I want the camera to do a full 360 degress turn arround, so that I start seeing my objects again. Just like in real-life when you stand still and "rotate" in a circle. So that after 360 degress I have my old vision back.

Comment: @noob Yes I no, You want to turn around "yourself". That is a rotation, isn't it. See the answer. Possibly you are interested in [this](https://github.com/Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl) (especially in the projects "WPF Orbit, pan, zoom" and "WPF First person")

Comment: @Rabbid76: OK, but one has to throw in at least one matrix transposition (intentional or unintentional by mixing up the storage layout) to make this work.

Comment: @derhass No, you don't have to. In OpenTK, just the matrix multiplication operates in the wrong order. Just the C# overloaded `*`-operator is implemented the wrong way. Nice, isn't it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 actually, matrix operator working in the wrong direction can be interpreted as 3 unintentional transposes, since `A*B = transpose(transpose(B)*transpose(A))`. But yeah, it is rather silly no matter how one is going to interpret it. I actually had already upvoted your other answer there, so I must have seen it before, but I forgot about it, probably because that situation is so silly... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look around you have to rotate `center` around `eye`.

e.g If you want to do a rotation around the x axis (up, down) the you have to setup a rotation matrix dependent on `_mouseDeltaY`:

```cs
float angle_degree = _mouseDeltaY;
Matrix4 rotateY = Matrix4.CreateRotationY(angle_degree * (float)Math.PI / 180.0f);
```

Compute the vector from `eye` to center and rotate it:

```cs
Vector3 toTarget = center - eye;
toTarget = Vector4.Transform(new Vector4(toTarget, 0.0f), rotateY).Xyz;
```

Finally compute the new center

```cs
center = eye + toTarget;
```

`eye` and `center` are assumed to be of type `Vector3`. Possibly  you have to change the scale of `_mouseDeltaY` for your needs.

Comment: Perfect, it's going. Now I gotta figure it out, how it works xD.